# Typescript cannot resolve module declared as webpack alias

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, alias, resolve

I have set up my webpack config to resolve a config file for `development` or `production`.

The folder structure is:

```
Project
 |    
 +-- config
   |  
    +-- development.ts
    +-- production.ts
```

The config file is just an object that is exported as the default:

```
const config = {
  errorUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/error',
  successUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
  branch: 'Branch',
  tag: 'Tag1',
  username: 'Demo client DEV',
  debug: true,
};

export default config;
```

I set up `paths` in my `tsconfig.json` with `baseUrl` as the project root `.`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build",
    "paths": {
      "@/pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "@/components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "Config": ["config/*"]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "coverage",
    "functional-test",
    "webpack.config.js",
    "jest.config.js",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec.tsx"
  ],
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "include": ["jest"]
  }
}
```

I added the resolve in the `webpack.config`:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx'],
  plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: './tsconfig.json' })],
  alias: {
    Config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'config/', argv.mode)
  }
},
```

Which I would have thought should resolve `development.ts` when I importthe file in a component like so `import config from 'Config';`

However I get the following TS error:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'Config' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I do not see what I am doing wrong here?

When I `console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, 'config/'));` it seeems to be the correct path as well so not sure why it is not resolving.